# Is there a 24th vigil?

Tags: bastion

So I'm nearing the end of my second playthrough going through new game plus.  I had already purchased everything I could in the first run, got all the idols, upgrades and whatnot.  But it feels like I've missed something:

[image: the mysterious 24th]

I could make stuff up all I want but is there a 24th vigil?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given the *Altruist* achievement (at least on Steam, can't comment on the Xbox version), which is "Complete 100 percent of the Vigils in the Memorial" and given I have that achievement and my vigil screen looked exactly like yours, we can safety assume that **there are only 23 vigils**.

Comment: 23 eh? Ok. It's just so hard to continue on seeing that hole there.

Comment: You could draw one on your computer screen. WOuld that help?

Comment: Conversely, the "Complete each trip to Who Knows Where" achievement is awarded after only three, not the fourth one you get in New Game+.